# "QSqlDatabase ob" crashes in QT!

Tags: qt, crash, database-connection, exe

in my development pc, the line "QSqlDatabase ob" doesn't crash & works just fine. But in a fresh pc moved the exe and it crashed but if i comment the above line and prepare the exe again it runs fine.

So I installed things that are required in the fresh pc to run qt from visual studio 2005, just to check whats the problem. Transferred the code there but from visual studio still it crashes for that very same line !!!

What are the dependencies of the simple line "QSqlDatabase ob" ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I did understand it right.
You compiled your project on your developement PC and want to move the compiled exe to a complete fresh PC, right?
Try to copy these files from your Qt4-SDK-installation to your folder with the compiled exe:

- mingwm10.dll
- QtCore4.dll
- QtGui4.dll
- QtSql4.dll

Now you can run your exe on every Windows-PC.